# Subscript out of range on template

Tags: excel, vba, templates, debugging

I have a question about VBA in Excel macro. I prepared a macro for a new worksheet but now my supervisor wants to create it into a template. Before my supervisor task everything works fine but when i made a template and run a macro i have a error 09 subscript out of range on template in that piece of code

```
For i = StartZakres To StopZakres
    Dim Dates As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Data = i
    Dates.Add Data, ""
Debug.Print Dates.Keys(Data)
Next i
```

I don't know where is the problem wihout template everything is working. Can u explain me where is the problem ?

Thanks,
David

Comment: You seem to be creating multiple instances of the same dictionary. Move the `Dim` statement outside the loop.

Comment: @Variatus - this is not true. You are mistaking the words `Set` and `Dim` probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sticking to the very issue of this question, i.s. the "subscript out of range" error you get, it's due to `Keys()` being a 0-based array

so either you're sure `StartZakres` starts from zero or you have to "compensate" any start value different from zero:

```
For i = StartZakres To StopZakres
    Dim Dates As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Data = i - StartZakres ' be sure to generate indexes always starting from zero
    Dates.Add Data, ""
    Debug.Print Dates.Keys(Data) + StartZakres ' print "real" key by adding the starting value of the loop
Next i
```

which would also work for negative values of `StartZakres`

Comment: That was a problem. The start of my loop was "zero" and i didn't saw it before. Thanks so much. The topic can be closed :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a minimal code that would work:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim i       As Long
    Dim Data    As Variant

    For i = 1 To 10
        Dim Dates As New Scripting.Dictionary
        Data = i
        Dates.Add i, "a" 'to print something
        Debug.Print Dates(Data)
    Next i

End Sub
```

In your case the mistake can be in the printing from the dictionary. You do not need the `.Keys` collection.

Comment: The printing is not working and that line should be removed by me. This is not a problem.

I think the problem is in switching between the source file where i get datas and the template file. I don't know how to switch that files.

Answer (score 0):

`Dim Dates As New Scripting.Dictionary` creates a new dictionary `Dates`. Called repetitively in a loop the new dictionary should replace the previous one and if your code would work the new dictionary would have exactly one item in it before it is replaced by a new one in the next cycle of the loop. I doubt that your code works because I expect the Dim statement to cause an error in itself. Therefore I suspect that your loop only runs once.

As @DisplayName has pointed out, there should be an issue with the line `Debug.Print Dates.Keys(Data)` depending upon the value of `Data`. I believe he has nailed the problem, and your code crashes on that line on the first loop. BTW, you haven't explained why you use both `i` and `Data` for the same value. The practise seems superfluous and may cause a problem they are of different datatype (which you have also kept a secret).

Most recently, you have pointed to a problem you have with switching between a template and another workbook. I find no reference to either the template or the source workbook in your original question. So, clearly this thread is taking on a life of its own: it's time to provide an answer.

The code below is tested and actually works. You can paste it into your workbook and try it. It has all the declarations (watch the datatypes) and all the code. Transpose the code into your project and it will work.

```
Private Sub TestDictionary()

    Dim StartZakres As Long
    Dim StopZakres As Long
    Dim Dates As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim i As Long

    StartZakres = 0
    StopZakres = 5
    Set Dates = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With Dates
        For i = StartZakres To StopZakres
            .Add i, Date + i
            Debug.Print .Item(i)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

If you want more information about the `Dictionary` object, you may like to visit [this site](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html). Everything is explained there in great detail, very patiently.

If you have a problem addressing workbooks (template or other) for the purpose of extracting values from them to put into your dictionary please ask another question. That problem isn't related to your current one.